# why get this error from TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dispatchEvent')

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, code-coverage

I'm doing unit test but I'm unable to get this error =>

"why get this error from TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dispatchEvent')"

```
   it('should have been clicked in primary action', () => {
      spyOn(component.primaryAction, 'emit');
      component.id = '1'; 

      fixture.detectChanges();

      const link = document.getElementById('primaryAct-1');

      spyOn(eventClick, 'stopPropagation');

      link.dispatchEvent(eventClick);
      console.log(link);

      expect(component.primaryAction.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
      expect(eventClick.stopPropagation).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

```
<div class="po-widget-xl" *ngIf="!secondaryLabel">
      <a class="po-widget-action" id="primaryAct[{{id}}]" [attr.my-id]="'someUniqueId'" (click)="runPrimaryAction($event)">{{ primaryLabel }}</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where are you creating the component?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it to a valid data type, such as `HTMLAnchorElement` since you are using `<a>`, also make sure the HTML element exists given its `id` or 'class':

```js
it('should have been clicked in primary action', () => {
      spyOn(component.primaryAction, 'emit');
      component.id = '1'; 

      fixture.detectChanges();

      const link = document.getElementById('primaryAct-1') as HTMLAnchorElement;

      spyOn(eventClick, 'stopPropagation');

      link.dispatchEvent(eventClick); // no longer null
      console.log(link);

      expect(component.primaryAction.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
      expect(eventClick.stopPropagation).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Comment: thank you very much I managed to perform the unit tests !